# VBA Code - Runtime 7 Error Message - out of memory

Tags: excel, vba

The code below receives a Runtime 7 Error Message - out of memory

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Var = InputBox("Enter the test, test")

    Dim myrange As Range
    Set myrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J50").Select

    For Each Cell In myrange.Cells
        If Cells.Value = Var Then
            Cell.Interior.Color = 255
        End If
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: No, the code below receives error 424 Object required.

Comment: Your code doesn't generate the error you've indicated. In addition, it contains a fairly obvious typo that I'd wager you can spot yourself by carefully reading the code, especially the line which generates the *Object required* error.

Comment: You do not need to `Select` the range that you set